# Conky transparency problem

Tags: release-freya, conky

Running Freya and attempting to get a good looking Conky window displaying. The pictures in the link only two ways I've been able to get it even display.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX7Pp.jpg

Image #1 is with these settings

```
# Window specifications #
gap_x 4000
gap_y 650
minimum_size 268 620
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type normal  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
#alignment middle_middle
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0
```

Image #2 is with these settings

```
# Window specifications #
gap_x 4000
gap_y 650
minimum_size 268 620
maximum_width 268
own_window yes
own_window_type normal  # other options are: override/dock/desktop/panel
#own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
#alignment middle_middle
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
```

Ideally what I'm looking for is image 1, but without all of the weird graphical glitches around it. Can someone point in the right direction settings wise? I've tried changing the value of *own_window_argb_value* and *own_window_type* with no luck. Either it wouldn't error out but wouldn't display anything, or it would error out and not display anything.

**12-2 Update**
Still no solution for this issue. Does anyone have different settings to try?

I'm using the Nvidia binary drivers (340.96) if that helps.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202089) discussion... he uses the root background, maybe the same lua command can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an issue with the transparency of the shadows.

Change `own_window_transparent yes` to `own_window_transparent no`.

It should fix the glitching:

[image]

Comment: I changed *own_window_transparent yes* to *no* and the window came up like the bottom of the image I posted, light and washed out. If I keep *own_window_transparent no* and comment out *own_window_argb_visual yes* and *own_window_argb_value 0* I get this: http://i.imgur.com/kdcnzGj.png